# How to determine the type of encryption used when using libmosquitto

Tags: c, aes, mqtt, tls1.2, libmosquitto

I am developing a C application for Linux using `libmosquitto` for the MQTT communication between my application and an MQTT broker elsewhere.

I am enabling TLS for authentication and encryption.

How do I actually find out which type of encryption is being used during the communication? **AES-256** is the requirement.

My MqttClient class :

```
#include <mosquittopp.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>

class MqttClient : public mosqpp::mosquittopp
{
   public:
       MqttClient(std::string name, uint16 id, std::string rev);
      ~MqttClient();
      void setConnectionInfo(std::string host, int port);
      void setUsernamePassw(std::string username, std::string password);
      void connect_client();
      int publish_message(const std::string _topic, const std::string _message, int QoS, bool retain);
      int subscribe_topic(const char * _message);
      const std::string getJsonString(const std::string _parameter, const std::string _value);
}
```

Elsewhere in the code I connect my client as follows ( Obviously this is just a code snippet with information missing, but just to show how I am using the class) :

```
MqttClient _mqttClient = new MqttClient("client1", 12345, "1");
_mqttClient->setConnectionInfo(_mqtt_params.host, _mqtt_params.portNum);
_mqttClient->setUsernamePassw(_mqtt_params.username, _mqtt_params.password);
_mqttClient->tls_set("/etc/certs/cert.pem", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
_mqttClient->tls_opts_set(1, "tlsv1.2", NULL);
_mqttClient->tls_insecure_set(FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third option of [`tls_opts_set`](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#mosquitto_tls_opts_set) is the ciphers you allow. Run `openssl ciphers` on your host to see what's available. You should be able to pass `AES256` here to get all the ciphers that include AES256, but if not, you can run `openssl ciphers AES` and use that colon-separated string.